# Create a Bitcoin wallet for users and get paid?

Tags: services, copay, wallet-development

Im a crypto trader and investor with a big portfolio. At the moment my company is looking to use GitHub of Copay to create a Bitcoin wallet with my company name, I want do a good investment in hardware and software and marketing.

How can we recover this investment or how we can get paid developing this? Is it possible to add a transaction fee for my company? Is there are any code to do that?

How we can earn money?

Comment: Are you aiming only for a wallet software as an end product or want to create an exchange on top of it? There are many wallet softwares which provide the service free of cost (as long as it is only wallet), and the softwares are well developed. You can earn money in case you wish to start an exchange.